# Number of elements in a list

Tags: differential-equations, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I have written the following program in mathematica.

```
{\[ScriptCapitalL], \[ScriptCapitalB]} = {-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}],
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]};
{vals, funs} = 
  DEigensystem[{\[ScriptCapitalL], \[ScriptCapitalB]}, 
   u[x, y], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}, 4];
 
vals
```

Now this gives output

```
{2,5,5,8}
```

Now I am going to bound by a certain number as follows.

```
Select[vals, # < 7 &]
```

This gives output

```
{2, 5, 5}
```

That is, `Select[vals, # < 7 &]` gives the elements less than or equal to 7.

Now, I am looking for a function such that Mathematica will tell me the number of elements in the list `Select[vals, # < 7 &]` . For, this case it is easy to see that the number is 3, but if we calculate a large number of eigenvalues then it will be difficult to calculate.

Thanking in advanced.

Comment: I think the function you are looking for is `Length`. Look i t up  in the documentation,

Answer (score 1):

```
vals = {2, 5, 5, 8};

Count[vals, x_ /; x < 7]
(*    3    *)
```